# Too few arguments to function Database\Seeders\DatabaseSeeder::Database\Seeders\{closure}()

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-seeding

I want to test my database and I have made factories and the following is my code inside my seeder file

```
public function run()
{
    Category::factory()->count(10)->create();

    User::factory()
        ->has(Profile::factory()->state(function (array $attributes, User $user) {
            return ['user_id' => $user->id];
        }))
        ->has(Post::factory()->count(50)
            ->state(function (array $attributes, User $user, Category $category) {
            return ['user_id' => $user->id, 'category_id' => $category->id];
        })
        ->has(Comment::factory()->count(3))
            ->state(function (array $attributes, User $user, Post $post) {
            return ['user_id' => $user->id, 'category_id' => $post->id];
        }))
        ->create();


}
```

I want to make some categories and 1 or more users with attached profiles, posts and comments. Can someone please check if my code is correct because it is giving the following error:

> Too few arguments to function
> Database\Seeders\DatabaseSeeder::Database\Seeders{closure}(), 2
> passed in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php
> on line 422 and exactly 3 expected
>
> at D:\xampp\htdocs\blog\database\seeders\DatabaseSeeder.php:28
> 24▕             ->has(Profile::factory()->state(function (array $attributes, User $user) {
> 25▕                 return ['user_id' => $user->id];
> 26▕             }))
> 27▕             ->has(Post::factory()->count(50)   ➜  28▕                 ->state(function (array $attributes, User $user, Category $category) {
> 29▕                 return ['user_id' => $user->id, 'category_id' => $category->id];
> 30▕             })
> 31▕             ->has(Comment::factory()->count(3))
> 32▕                 ->state(function (array $attributes, User $user, Post $post) {
>
> 1
> D:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php:422
> Database\Seeders\DatabaseSeeder::Database\Seeders{closure}(Object(App\Models\User))
>
> 2
> D:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php:741
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories{closure}(Object(Closure))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your second and third closure:

```
->state(function (array $attributes, User $user, Category $category)
```

You cannot expect more than `$attributes` and created parent model (`$user` in this case). This `$category` parameter causes the problem, you need to acquire this object outside closure.